# Getting the DISQUS Comments number from dynamic pages and populate MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, disqus

DISQUS commenting system is nice. API is confusing me a bit, so if anyone can please guide me to the right directions.

What I want to do is to get the total number of comments from dynamic pages/posts and insert that number to a MySQL table so I can filter the posts of those pages according to the total comments number and display each post's comment number in the forontapage, sidebars etc. Of course, I would like to update those rows later with a function I'll create when new comments pop up. But what I am asking is just the way I can get them.

Below my disqus_indentifier:

`var disqus_identifier = <?php echo $post_id ?>;`

Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind! I think I found the answer: http://docs.disqus.com/developers/universal/#comment-count, #disqus_thread is what I am looking for :)

Comment: Any ideas how to populate the db now? I got the comments count...

Answer (score 2):

As you discovered, the [Disqus comment count script](http://docs.disqus.com/developers/universal/#comment-count) is definitely the best solution for what you're trying to do. It doesn't require any API integration or database work. Simply paste the code on your site and it will automatically find the counts for all comment count links on the page and show the relevant Disqus comment count for each.

For anyone looking to do more granular work along these lines via our API, the best endpoint would probably be [threads/details](http://disqus.com/api/docs/threads/details/) which returns the details for a thread (including the number of comments). As far as inserting that information into your database I'd recommend looking over [basic SQL INSERT documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp).

We've also put together some [sample API recipes](https://github.com/thetylerhayes/DISQUS-API-Recipes) which can help you jumpstart your API integration, including a threads/details PHP script.

Comment: Thanks @Tyler, thread/details was what I was looking for. I was just asking how to get the comments number and then I would include that to a function to populate the db. Can I ask you one more thing. Is there a way to invoke a php function when a new comment appear in a post/page? Thanks again for your informative and detailed answer.

Comment: @weigruf We offer a public callback which fires when new comments are posted. That may be what you're looking for. http://docs.disqus.com/help/60/

Comment: @TylerHayes That's fine if you're using `href="http://foo.com/bar.html`, but what if you're using php action and passing in variables as navigation: `<a href=".?action=viewimage&site=comics&id=63">Link</a>`. Where do I append `#disqus_thread` in this case?